# Feynman lectures

Tags: resource-recommendations

I have a basic knowledge in several fields of physics. I aspire to study further in electromagnetism and quantum mechanics. I have  fundamental knowledge in calculus. Are Feynmann's lectures appropriate for me? I mean do they contain advanced mathematical concepts?

Comment: Feynman lectures do not have problems to practice but gives a good conceptual understanding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for feedback on specific resources is not within our scope.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to assess what is considered an advanced mathematical concept. What might be difficult to me, may be easy to another person and vice versa. However, as you aspire to study electromagnetism and QM mechanics have you considered the [video lecture series by Leonard Susskind](http://theoreticalminimum.com/courses)? He covers physics from classical mechanics to general relativity and beyond. They are excellent and contain both the courses you are looking for. If you are interested in introductory electricity and magnetism then there is always the [Walter Lewin course on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=walter%20lewin%20electricity%20and%20magnetism%208.02). Feynman lectures are excellent as an introduction. By this I mean volume I. Unfortunately there are some typos and mistakes in the remaining volumes. If I were you I would check out the other resources that I have recommended as they are excellent IMO. Also, Griffiths has two introductory books given below (Both excellent aswell)

[Griffiths - Electrodynamics](http://kestrel.nmt.edu/~mce/Electromagnetics_by_Griffiths-1.pdf)

[Griffiths - QM](http://www.fisica.net/quantica/Griffiths%20-%20Introduction%20to%20quantum%20mechanics.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't read the third volume yet the first and second volume doesn't contain complex mathematics. Dr. Feynman tried to explain things in a very logical and simpler way and tried to provoke questions in the mind of readers. Feynman emphasized more on the concepts of physics rather mathematics. These books are worth reading, at least anybody who loves physics will love these books.